# SocketIO server, express and http modules

Tags: http, express, socket.io, chat

Almost every SocketIO server example, whether for chat or something simpler, seem to start by requiring the following 2 modules like so

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var socket = require('socket-io-server');
```

I need to create a simple SocketIO server that does NOT use the web or a browser in any way. It is simple listening for either TCP or websockets. There is only a maximum of 2 clients connecting at one time. When it receives a "TRIGGER" message from one client it emits or broadcasts a "START" message to the 2nd client
DO I still need to use express and the http modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start just a socket.io server all by itself like this:

```
var io = require('socket.io')();
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('Socket connection established');
});
io.listen(3000);
```

When started this way, it will create it's own server. Internally, it still uses the `http` module to make the server, but you don't have to explictly use that module yourself.

There is no need for Express if you don't need/want the other capabilities that Express offers.